# Set DNN Tab URL programmatically

Tags: url, dotnetnuke

I'm creating pages using the DNN API as follows:

```
public int AddPage(string name, string title, string url, int parentPageID = 0)
{
    TabController pageManager = new TabController();
    TabInfo newPage = new TabInfo();
    newPage.PortalID = _PortalID;
    newPage.TabName = name;
    newPage.Title = title;
    newPage.ParentId = parentPageID;
    newPage.SkinPath = "/path-to-skin";
    newPage.SkinSrc = "/path-to-skin/skin-name.ascx";
    int newPageID = pageManager.AddTab(newPage);

    TabUrlInfo tabUrlInfo = new TabUrlInfo();
    tabUrlInfo.TabId = newPageID;
    tabUrlInfo.Url = url;
    tabUrlInfo.HttpStatus = "200";
    tabUrlInfo.SeqNum = 1;
    newPage.TabUrls.Add(tabUrlInfo);
    pageManager.UpdateTab(newPage);

    var parentPage = GetPage(parentPageID);
    _AddDDRMenuToPage(newPageID, parentPage.TabName);
    return newPageID;
}
```

That TabUrlInfo approach has no affect and newPage.Url sets the page as a link. 
The property I'm looking to change is: 
[image]

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

**EDIT:**
I got one step further by using this line of code:

```
PageManager.SaveTabUrl(tabUrlInfo, _PortalID, true);
```

Which replaces these two lines:

```
newPage.TabUrls.Add(tabUrlInfo);
pageManager.UpdateTab(newPage);
```

Using SaveTabUrl saves a record in the TabUrls table correctly but when I try to go to page settings I get a 404 error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `TabController` > `SaveTabUrl`. This is from DNN 7.3 and above.

```
//create a new tabcontroller instance
TabController controller = new TabController();

//create a new tab with some properties
TabInfo newTab = new TabInfo();
newTab.PortalID = 0;
newTab.TabName = "TabNaam";
newTab.Title = "TabTitel";

//add the new tab and get it's new tabid
int newTabId = controller.AddTab(newTab);

//create a new taburlinfo insance and set some propeties
TabUrlInfo tabUrl = new TabUrlInfo();
tabUrl.TabId = newTabId;
tabUrl.SeqNum = 0;
tabUrl.Url = "/dit-is-een-test";
tabUrl.HttpStatus = "200";

//save the url info
controller.SaveTabUrl(tabUrl, PortalId, true);
```

Comment: Yip I came to the same point as you can see in my edit, but the one thing that I didn't know is that you can't specify the URL value with spaces in them so I did a replace changing spaces with hyphens.